# Having trouble figuring out the way to solve Array Problem

Tags: algorithm

Please help me to get any idea.
Below is a short description about what we have to do.

> Input : Array
>    Output : index {i, j} ( i = j allowed) with maximum
>   Appeal Appeal = A[i] +A[j] + abs(i-j)
>
> Example
>   input: A = {1, 3, -1}
>   output: {1, 1}
>   Appeal = A[1] + A[1] + abs(1-1) = 3 + 3+ 0 = 6

```
public int[] maxAppealPair(int[] A){
    if(A==null || A.length==0) return new int[] {-1,-1};

    int start=0, end=A.length-1;
    int m1, m2;
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while(start <= end){
        int curr = A[start] + A[end] + Math.abs(start-end);
        if(curr > max){
           max = curr;
           m1 = start, m2 = end;
        }
     }
 }
```

And here is my coding so far.

First I tried to solve this using two pointer 
but the problem is
To use two pointer(start,end) we should sort the array, but if we sort the array, how to know the indices in the end?

but if the array is unsorted, What should I do on my start, end pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets break your given condition.

```
a[i] + a[j] + abs(i-j)
```

this can be written in 2 ways removing the abs()

```
a[i] + a[j] + i - j
a[i] + a[j] - i + j
```

so

```
(a[i] + i) + ( a[j] - j) and
(a[i] - i) + (a[j] + j)
```

So you just need to make 2 arrays in which one stores sum of element with its index and in other you have difference. Than just select maximum element from those 2 list and that will be maximum value. Here's the code

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
temp1 = list()
temp2 = list()
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
    temp1.append(a[i]-i)
    temp2.append(a[i]+i)
maxi1 = INT_MIN
maxi2 = INT_MIN
for i in range(n):
    if maxi1 < temp1[i]:
        maxi1 = temp1[i]
        index1 = i
    if maxi2 < temp2[i]:
        maxi2 = temp2[i]
        index2 = i
print(index1,index2)
```

Just take care when size of list is less than 2.

Comment: Instead of using 2 list to store every element we can just use 2 variables to store maximum from both the case by just modifying for loop. That would reduce space complexity to O(1) which is O(n) in our current solution.